# Reading from a configuration file

Tags: c, file-io, fgets

I'm working on reading a path from a simple configuration file and store it in to a char array using C language. I came up with a way to do that but have a problem with retrieving the path without white spaces attached the end of it. Please help me to find a better way of doing this.

```
char* webroot(){
 FILE *in = fopen("conf", "rt");
 char buff[1000];
 fgets(buff, 1000, in);
 printf("first line of \"conf\": %s\n", buff);
 fclose(in);

 return buff;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a sequence of whitespace characters at end but the new-line character, as [`fgets()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) includes it in the returned buffer: replace the `\n` with a null terminator:

```
/* fgets() will not read the new-line if
   there is not sufficient space in the buffer
   so ensure it is present. */
char* nl_ptr = strrchr(buff, '\n');
if (nl_ptr) *nl_ptr = '\0';
```

It may appear as though there is a sequence of whitespace characters because of the apparent line wrapping on `stdout`, but it is due to the presence of the new-line character read by `fgets()`.

When printing strings I find it useful to place the string inside `[]` to make the content of the string clearer:

```
printf("first line of \"conf\": [%s]\n", buff);
```

this would make the presence of the new-line character obtained by `fgets()` more visible.

Note that the function `webroot()` is returning the address of the local variable `buff`: this is an error and is undefined behaviour. A new buffer will need to be dynamically allocated, using `strdup()` if available or `malloc()` and `strcpy()` otherwise:

```
return strdup(buff);
```

the caller of `webroot()` must `free()` the returned value. Arrange that `NULL` is returned if a failure occurs.

Comment: Depending on the OS, you may also have a '\r' character.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fscanf(fp, "%s", buff)` to read a string without spaces. To prevent a buffer overflow add a limit `fscanf(fp, "%999s", buff)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using fscanf?

```
fscanf(in, "%s", buff);
```